# Auto resize application

Tags: android, android-layout

I have already created quite a nice android application. I worked hard on the design and the interface
and. Today I was reported that my app looks really bad on samsung galaxy ace which has only 480/320 resolution. It seams to be quite reasonable now as I tested in on htc desire hd (800/480)  but didn't think about it.

My question is if I can easily make it look good on all resolutions? I wouldn't like to create another layout for each one. Moreover as I wasn't thinking about it while creating I wouldn't like to fix every single label now - to avoid errors. Is there a 'global' solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a utility that will resize all your layouts,
it's a pixel perfect type resize, ie application will scale
without consideration for asthetics

http://www.evildevices.com/ed-main/?page_id=51